# Manual click event trigger in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

How to dispatch an click event :

for example `<mx:Button id="btn" click="someFunction();">`

by manual event dispatch how to call that `someFunction();`

Comment: what do you mean under "manual"? click on some other flex control? you mean automatically dispatch it?

Comment: manual .means i wann dispatch without clicking that button

Comment: Just call the function 'someFunction()' from within your code. In the function declaration use 'event:MouseEvent = null' as the parameter, google the null part if needs be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is call the handler without clicking the button, just do this somewhere in your ActionScript code:

```
someFunction();
```

In your sample, you aren't passing the event parameter to the function.  But, if you want to do that, you'll have to create your own [MouseEvent](http://www.few.vu.nl/~eliens/assets/flex3/langref/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) object.  Something like this:

```
var myFakeMouseEvent: MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK);
// set other properties on the mouse event
someFunction(myFakeMouseEvent);
```

If you want to dispatch the click event without clicking the buttonn, you can do this:

```
var myFakeMouseEvent: MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK);
// set other properties on the mouse event
objectToDispatchEvent.dispatchEvent(myFakeMouseEvent);
```